# Unable to run Echo Bot Google Messaging API. Doesn't reply to "card", "carousel", "chips" strings

Tags: gcloud

I just started Google Messaging APIs 3-5 days ago and couldn't figure out what did I go wrong. I already sent/asked this issue to Google's Support page.

Project is under my generic google account. I created a Service Account under this project for info@ourdomain.com and added it as a Project > Editor role. Got this Json keys, uploaded them together with my python Echo Bot files.

Done registering my partner account as well (info@ourdomain.com) and got verified with the Project Number connected that's in my generic google account. I don't know if this is the right setup where my partner account and project ID are from different Google Accounts (info@ourdomain.com and generic@gmail.com, respectively).

Echo bot sample I used: https://github.com/google-business-communications/bm-python-echo-bot/tree/master/full_sample

[image]

Logs:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very familiar with programming Google's services but was unaware of Business Messages until I saw your question (it's interesting, thanks).

There are a couple of references to "select the project that you registered for Business Messages".

Often Google enable non-GA|non-public APIs and other functionality (sometimes by injecting service accounts into the project's policy) by having users register Project IDs and Google accounts. I suspect that's what's happening here and the functionality is either blocked or not working entirely by your use of a different Project.

You may be able to gain more insight from the problem by checking logs. IIUC, an App Engine app is deploy and you should be able to `gcloud app logs read --project=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]` (or `gcloud app logs tail --project=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]`)

Comment: thanks @DazWilkin I updated my comment with another screenshot of the log. I couldn't find any docs about the logs I'm seeing.

Comment: The logs contain many `404`s ("not found") on `/`. The App Engine app appears to only implement a handler on `/callback`. When you registered the app, there was an option to specify a callback URL. I think that needs to be updated too.

Comment: @geeksified Does it answers your question ?

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks DazWilkin. The /callback appended at the end of the webhook URL (https://PROJECT_ID.xx.x.appspot.com/callback) does the job! It didn't matter if the project is from generic google account or from any google account as long as you added the other email as an owner/editor of the project. The /callback sure fixed it!